# How do we name two chords a third apart from each other?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

I know there is a term for two diatonic chords that are a thrid apart (and thus sharing 2 or more notes), but I forgot it.

Examples :

- Am and C
- Gm7 and Bb
- IV-vi
- vi-I
- etc.

Comment: If you meant Gm7 and *Bb6*, then those are *inversions* of each other.

Comment: @Tim I guess Gm7 and Bb6 would fit my description, but I'm not looking for the term inversion, which does not always apply for these chords (see: Am and C)

Comment: Things get a bit tricky when talking about relative _chords_ because relative is really a term applied to _keys_. By extension it gets used to describe chord relationships.

Comment: in German they are called "Terz verwandt". This means third-related. The scales and keys are called relative keys, but I would call them diatonic third-relations, while  mediants seem to go under "chromatic third relation." https://www.jstor.org/stable/745872?seq=1

Answer (score 1):

For those examples - where the chords are diatonic, belonging to one key - you can call them *relative major and minor*. Usually the usage is one chord referring to the other: "`Am` is the relative minor of `C` major" or "`C` major is the relative major of `Am`."

There is another kind of chord pairing where the roots are a third apart but not in the same key, and sharing the same chord quality: *[chromatic mediants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_mediant)*. Very different from your example, but I you might want to be aware.

You didn't ask, but it also may be interesting to point out a few common progressions featuring relative chords:

- in rock/pop the "doo wop" progression `I vi IV V`, or it's common to just vamp back and forth between `I` and `vi`.
- Baroque and early classical often used roots by descending thirds like `I vi IV ii...` where the first two chord are relatives.
- from the same time period there are two harmonic sequences that feature moves between relative pairs. *Falling thirds* in major `I V6` sequenced to the relative minor `vi iii6`, the other one in minor doesn't have a name I know of but can be seen in examples like Handel's *Sarabande in D Minor* or the *Passamezzo Antico* ground bass where `i V` is then sequenced at the relative major `III VII`.

The reason I mention these examples is because root movement by third is often described as a *weak progression*. Obviously it isn't weak in the sense of *ineffective* when it is so commonly used. *Weak* in this sense more or less means root progression not by fifth. It does seem significant that these various progressions involve one of the relative chords being a tonic and then somewhere dominant harmony is used to make the tonality clear.

---

Strictly speaking "relative" is a descriptor for *keys*. From Grove's dictionary...

[image]

...but people commonly use relative to describe chord relationships.

As the term applies to *keys* it's no surprise that when talking about chord relationships, relatives imply one or the other chord is a tonic, like `I` and `vi` in major keys or `i` and `III` in minor keys.

Comment: Yes, my question is in the case the chords are diatonic, I could add that to the question. I hoped to find a term less specific than relative maj/min, I feel like relative maj/min is only expressing the vi-I, where I'd like a term that would also work for IV-vi, V-vii°, etc... Have you heard the term "mediants chords" ? I feel like this could be the term I'm looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Based on the term "chromatic mediants", we could imagine it could be called "diatonic mediants" ? Or just "mediants", since diatonic is often implicit. It seems to be the same concept.

Comment: Oh I just realised that mediant chord is already refering to the third scale degree of a diatonic scale, so that would be a confusing choice of words.

Comment: Yeah, relative major/minor does imply (at least to me) one chord or the other is a tonic. I don't know of another more generic, but widely used term. "Root progression by third" would be the concise description. I don't think anyone would misconstrue that to include chromatic mediants which a special enough that people use the term whenever they are present.

Comment: I thought I heard such a term in a video of the YouTube channel 12tone. But maybe I don't remember well, or maybe he used a not widely used term, or an incorrect one. Thank you for your hindsights, they're welcome ;) I'll leave the question open, if it happens someone would know such a more generic term to describe this. As for "Progression by third", it was not what I recall of it, but I guess it would fit the description !

Comment: I will add a note to my answer about why it applies best to tonic pairs.